# Filtering generic select with changeable parameters

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, where-clause

I'll keep it simple. I have an API endpoint that receives 0 to 3 parameters. The get method look like this:

```
[HttpGet("filtrar")]
public ActionResult<List<TipoDocumento>> GetAllPorFiltro(string sigla, int? status, string descricao)
{
    return _tipoDocumentoRepositorio.GetAllByFilter(????);
}
```

The _tipoDocumentoRepositorio is an interface that has DI, and the method GetAllByFilter() in the class that implements it looks like this:

```
public List<T> GetAllByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return _someContexto.Set<T>()
        .Where(filter)
        .ToList();
}
```

The fact is: even though I put a function on ???? (like

```
f => f.Sigla.Equals(sigla)
```

), it keeps me returning an empty List. What am I doing wrong? Or what else should I do to make it work?

Obs: I can't put all of the code here cause it's not mine, but I can argue. To be sure: I'm using EF (and Migration and sort, I'm new in C#). And any links to other SO question that may answer my question is welcomed as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that `string.Equals` is case-sensitive so `"Hello Worlds"` isnt equals to `"hello worlds"`.

Comment: I do, but I have tried both, and none made it. I don't know if I have to do some modifications on the migration or something else (I'll edit it to ensure I'm using EF on the project)...

Comment: Any reason you are using `Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter` instead of only `Func<T, bool> filter` ?

Comment: @RandRandom: because he is using EF and EF translates the Expression<> to SQL. The Func<> is never executed in C#.

Comment: None. I saw it on one of the hundreds solutions I tried before. I'll try your sugestion.

Comment: I think, whether it is case sensitive depends on the DB and the collation used. SQL-Server is by default case-insensitive, Oracle is by default case sensitive.

Comment: I'm using ef core

Comment: Try using a SQL profiler to see what query is sent to the DB.

Comment: Just Func<T, bool> didn't work. I'll try to verify the query sent to the DB.

Comment: Func<T,bool> is simply wrong. It may work sometimes but then it means: Read all records from db, then transfer them all to my application and then filter them in memory. Not what you normally want to do...

Comment: The query sent to DB: SELECT t.cd_categoria, t.cd_status, t.dc_tipo_documento, t.sigla_tipo_documento
FROM dbo.tipo_documento AS t. It's all correct but the WHERE clause and, although it's not int the query, it doesn't return ALL lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `GetAllByFilter` to just `GetAll()` and return just `IQueriable<T>`

Create an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

Use it like that:

```
[HttpGet("filtrar")]
public ActionResult<List<TipoDocumento>> GetAllPorFiltro(string sigla, int? status, string descricao)
{
     var res = _tipoDocumentoRepositorio
        .GetAll()
        .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sigla), q => q.sigla == sigla)
        .WhereIf(status.HasValue, q => q.sigla == sigla.Value)
        .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descricao), q => q.descricao == descricao)
        .ToList();
     ...
}
```